# Snowflake regex with rlike to return a bool gives unexpected result

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Want a bool back 1 or 0 if field 'name' contains string 'IOS_PROD'. Tried:

```
case when rlike(c.name, 'IOS_PROD') then 1 else 0 end as IOS
```

Returns all 0s instead of a mix of 1s and 0s as expected. How can I regex and return 1 or 0 in this way?

Verified the underlying data with:

```
select name, count(1) from table group by 1
```

For sure, there are mixes of cases where name contains 'IOS_PROD' and does not, so it's my regex that's flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if this returns `0`s, then there is not match.

Second, you can use the built-in SQL `LIKE` operator for this:

```
(case when c.name like '%IOS\_PROD%' then 1 else 0 end) as IOS
```

One problem could be the uppercase versus lowercase, so perhaps:

```
(case when upper(c.name) like '%IOS\_PROD%' then 1 else 0 end) as IOS
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's a case sensitivity issue. Try:

```
case when c.name ILIKE '%IOS\_PROD%' then 1 else 0 end as IOS
```

[ILIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ilike.html) performs case-insensitive matching.

Comment: If it's a regex match still with rlike what do the %s do? Just curious? Would it not be stars instead \*string\*?

Comment: it's not a regex; not sure why you think you need a regex?

Answer (score 1):

`snowflake-cloud-data-platform` is the correct tag.

A boolean value has the values TRUE/FALSE. 0 and 1 are numbers. The value of them over BOOLEAN values depends on if you are going to to math or logic on the results.

[RLIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike.html) can be made to be case insensitive with the 'i' [parameter](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#parameters), thus

```
case when rlike(c.name, 'IOS_PROD', 'i') then 1 else 0 end as IOS
```

should work if c.name is lower/mixed case. But given

> RLIKE is similar to the LIKE function, but with POSIX extended regular expressions instead of SQL LIKE pattern syntax.

and you are not using any regex tokens it makes more sense to use the LIKE or case insensitive ILIKE, but then if you are want sub-string matching like Mitch notes you will need to add `%` wild card matches at the front/end

Also in Snowflake you can use the [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html) which is tidy way to frame this SQL

```
IFF( rlike(c.name, 'IOS_PROD', 'i'), 1, 0) as IOS
```